# Transform dput(remove) data.frame from txt file into R object with commas

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, colors

I have a txt file (`remove.txt`) with these kind of data (that's RGB Hex colors):

```
"#DDDEE0", "#D8D9DB", "#F5F6F8", "#C9CBCA"...
```

Which are colors I don't want into my analysis.

And I have a `R` object (`nacreHEX`) with other data like in the file, but there are into this the good colors and the colors wich I don't want into my analysis. So I use this code to remove them:

`nacreHEX <- nacreHEX [! nacreHEX %in% remove]` .

It's works when `remove` is a `R` object like this `remove <- c("#DDDEE0", "#D8D9DB"...)`, but it doesn't work when it's come from a txt file and I change it into a `data.frame`, and neither when I try with `remove2 <-as.vector(t(remove))`.

So there is my code:

```
remove <- read.table("remove.txt", sep=",")
remove2 <-as.vector(t(remove))
nacreHEX <- nacreHEX [! nacreHEX %in% remove2]
head(nacreHEX)
```

With this, there are no comas with `as.vector`, so may be that's why it doesn't work.

How can I make a `R` vector with comas with these kind of data?
What stage did I forget?

Comment: If your text file has spaces in it like you show, then those spaces could be causing the problem. Trying running `trimws()` on your vector-from-data.frame. This is just a guess right now -- it would be very clear if you post `dput(remove)` in your question, where `remove` is the `read.table` output.

Comment: And that's works ! I've made the edit. Thanks @Gregor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your txt file is separated by `", "` not `",'`. The spaces end up in your string:

```
rr = read.table(text = '"#DDDEE0", "#D8D9DB", "#F5F6F8", "#C9CBCA"', sep = ",")
(rr = as.vector(t(rr)))
# [1] "#DDDEE0"  " #D8D9DB" " #F5F6F8" " #C9CBCA"
```

You can see the leading spaces before the `#`. We can trim these spaces with `trimws()`.

```
trimws(rr)
# [1] "#DDDEE0"  "#D8D9DB" "#F5F6F8" "#C9CBCA"
```

Even better, you can use the argument `strip.white` to have `read.table` do it for you:

```
    rr = read.table(text = '"#DDDEE0", "#D8D9DB", "#F5F6F8", "#C9CBCA"',
                    sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE)
```